# Fondo de Imagen en Modal

Tags: bootstrap, modal

Buen día
Quería consultar, es posible, poner una imagen de fondo cuando se abre una modal?
Es decir, quiero que se muestre la imagen por detrás de la modal. Lo intenté, y con colores me funciona, le puedo cambiar el color del fondo, pero no logro hacer que me coloque una imagen de fondo.

He hecho esto con mi Css, pero solo me funciona al cambiar el color. Si me pudieran ayudar, gracias

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
background-image: url('../../../../lib/assets/sysTemplate/assets/images/inventario/fondo-modal-proveedores.svg');
```

}

Comment: Prueba cambiando `.modal-backdrop.show` por `.modal-backdrop`

Comment: ya lo probé y si me funciona. Pero acabo de ver que tenía también el error en donde estaba enlazando el archivo css. Asi que ya lo cambie y me funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias